# Do here-strings undergo word-splitting?

Tags: linux, bash, herestring

Quoting [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) and `man bash` (version 4.3):

> `[n]<<< word`
>
> The *`word`* undergoes brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and
>   variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and
>   quote removal. Pathname expansion and word splitting are not
>   performed.

The `word` should not undergo word-splitting. However, using this simple code:

```
var="a    b"

cat <<< $var
#output:
#a b

cat <<< "$var"
#output:
#a    b
```

What am I missing? Does this depend on the version of `bash` or is there a mistake in the manual? I am using `GNU bash, version 4.3.48`.

Comment: Unlikely a version thing: I get the same with ```GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)```

Comment: On my bash 4.4.12(1), both versions of the `cat` command produce the same output (with no word-splitting).

Comment: @John1024 I guess it is corrected in `bash 4.4`. The part about no word-splitting is still present in my `bash 4.3` manual from 2014 February though.

Comment: @PesaThe To clarify, my `man bash` (version 4.4) says _no_ word splitting is performed and a repeat of your tests on my machine shows _no_ word splitting.

Comment: Fwiw, ```man bash``` on OSX Sierra (the above mentioned version of bash) says nothing about word splitting for here strings.

Comment: @TylerH This question asks about here-strings in particular, not about strings in general. I had to rollback your edit.

Comment: @PesaThe Thanks, the issue was that without the hyphen it looked like a random word incorrectly inserted into the question.

Comment: @TylerH Yep, looks better now, thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The change from splitting here-strings to not splitting them happened between bash-4.4-alpha and bash-4.4-beta. Quoting from [`CHANGES`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES#n437):

> Bash no longer splits the expansion of here-strings, as the documentation has always said.

So the manuals of older Bash versions mentioned it, but didn't actually do it.

Comment: Nice find! I know where to look for things like this at last.  I checked that versions prior to 4.3 didn't mention word-splitting at all but since 4.3 it has been present in manuals. For sure took them a while to comply with it.