# bash "<<<" prints multiline variable on one line

Tags: bash

Why `<<<$x` removes new line char?

```
> cat <<<"A
B" # prints two lines (as expected)
A
B

> x="A
B"
> cat <<<"$x" # prints two lines (again, as expected)
A
B

> cat <<<$x # prints one line (..Why only one line!? I would expected two lines, or just "A", or error; Who's eating up the new line?)
A B
```

How come did the new line disappear? Is it convenience thingy specially for `<<<`?
Are there other situations where similar thing happen? (apart from `<<<$var`)

Nothing relating to new lines in here: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html
(if relevant: GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release)

Comment: It undergoes word splitting, therefore you lose the whitespaces. In future versions of bash, variables that are part of here-strings no longer undergo word-splitting, but in version 4.2, they still do.

Comment: @PesaThe Please paste your first comment as an answer (i.e. version specific behavior, of word splitting) - I'll mark accepted. Anyway: is it special/scoped word splitting? With "usual" word splitting: `f="long name"; touch $f` creates two files, because command was `touch long name`.  If `<<<` would use usual word splitting, then `x="A B"; cat <<<$x` would run command `cat <<<A B`, which is redirect "A" to stdin, while B is the first arg of the command. Which is not what happened. Word splitting for `<<<` seems to be "scoped". Any other examples of such scoped splitting?

Comment: `<<< word` redirects the `word` to stdin. You can sort of imagine it as doing `echo $x | cat`.

Comment: Here is a related question I once had where the specific versions are mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744854/do-here-strings-undergo-word-splitting

Comment: `bash` 4.2 had issues with unquoted here-strings. `$x` wasn't *supposed* to undergo word-spitting, but it did. The issue is fixed to some extent in 4.3 and more completely in 4.4.